# Parse array element containing comma-separated and quoted strings to generate a new array of elements

Tags: php, arrays, split, text-parsing

Now my array is Storing values like

```
Array([0] => "Aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
```

How can I make this Array as below using PHP

```
Array[0] = "Aaa", Array[1] = "bbb", Array[2] = "ccc"
```

How to make like this. I tried with explode its not taking values correctly.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: I jsut push array of values with double quotes and pass in PHP and I cannot access each value in array

Comment: Can you var_dump your array and put results here?

Comment: Array([0] => "Aaa", "bbb", "ccc") this is what Im getting while var_dump i Jst what thes values should save in seperate index

Comment: $newarray = explode(',',$oldarray); it is showing array[0] with "Aaa" I dont want that double quotes Simply I want the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$oldarray[0]='"abc","def","hij"';
$oldarray[1]='"abc","def","hij"';
$newarray=array();
foreach ($oldarray as $value) {
    $newarray[] = str_replace('"','',explode(',',$value));
    //print_r($value);die();
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: It splits and save in seperate index but It will not save with double quotes in String

Comment: can u share complete code here ? and output which u want

Comment: Actually Its very Big Part.I cant share complete code

Comment: you are getting double quotes in every string right ? and you want to remove double quotes?

Comment: Yes obsolutely Viral

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126071/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-viral-barot).

Answer (score 3):

Use `explode` to split the value in multiple values based on the coma, use str_replace to remove the quotes  :

you do something like this

```
$newarray = explode(',',str_replace('"', "",$oldarray[]));
```

or:

```
$newarray = explode('","',trim($oldarray[],'"'));
```

[docs](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.explode.php)

Comment: If I give array[0] it jst get frst value alone

Comment: This is not retrieving any value simply returns 0th index as empty

Comment: If the String is like in this case "Entrusting upon credible vendors for high-grade raw materials, we manufacture and supply premium quality Car Bumper." It explode till raw materials, as index1 and remaining in index 2 but I want total sentence as single index

Comment: try something like: `$newarray = explode('","',trim($oldarray[],'"'));`

Comment: Ya thts great Now Its splited in correct Way Thats alot Madalin

Answer (score 3):

Use `explode`

Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter comma.

```
$array1 = explode(',',$array[0]);
```

Use `str_replace` to remove double quotes

```
 str_replace('"', '', $array[0]);
 $array1 = explode(',',str_replace('"', '',$array[0]));
```

Check `array1[0]`, `array1[1]` and `array1[2]` to find your values

Comment: I tried this already it will not get any value in array everything is empty

Answer (score 0):

You have quote-wrapped values in a regularly formatted csv string -- there is a native tool for parsing that.  Call `str_getcsv()` on the first element and save it back to the original array variable if you like.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1VPmc))

```
$array = ['"Aaa", "bbb", "ccc"'];

$array = str_getcsv($array[0]);

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Aaa',
  1 => 'bbb',
  2 => 'ccc',
)
```